CSS not serving in self hosted Nginx with PHP in docker
I have moved from a webhost online, to selfhosting my own server. I installed nginx and php via docker and it works to a point (when I visit the domain it is linked to, it loads the index and it can call the javascript on the site with on problems. However, it does not call the CSS file at all, so it has no styling. It doesnt show any issues in the log, and I can also navigate to the .css file it is calling successfully.).
Any ideas on how to get this to work? This is my current nginx.conf file:
events {}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|otf)$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      expires 30d;  # Cache static files for 30 days
      # access_log off;  # Optionally disable access log for static files
    }
  }
}


What does the network connection debug tab in your browser show for the request?

Simple and most easiest solution is to open your webpage in the browser and take the view-source of the page. It will show you the path from where the CSS is loading and you can easily fix it accordingly.

" it does not call the CSS file at all" - what does that mean? If your browser doesn't even request the CSS files, how is this problem related to PHP, CSS, Docker, nginx or [tag:self-hosting]?

It can't be an issue with paths, because the file structure is exactly the same as when I hosted via hostinger and other only webhosts. The website is website.hansramzan.com if you want to see what the issue is

You can try out following:

Check are your CSS files are located under /var/www/html

Add logging to the CSS location block to debug further:


location ~* \.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|otf)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires 30d;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/static.log;  # Enable logging for static files
}


It will log requests for static files

As I mentioned also in comment, simple and most easiest solution is to open your webpage in the browser and take the view-source of the page. It will show you the path from where the CSS is loading and show you the full path of the CSS. This will help you to fix the path issue.


I think it's pulling the css actually (you can view the website here: website.hansramzan.com) but still not sure why it's not working

@HansRamzan Its not opening.

Strange, it loads up for me

Check the path and use some other system to see the actual results. If you are in Windows then create a new user account and then test. I believe something is loading from your local path
